Getting blank values from formdata, axios in laravel api
I am getting no input values in laravel backend api. I have a small script in nodejs to upload users. The script was working last day. But today its not working i didn't changed any code :/
const axios = require('axios');
const download = require('image-downloader');
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');

Function to post data to API
async function post_in_api(api_data) {
    try {
        const form = new FormData();
        for (let key in api_data) {
            if (key !== 'photos') {
                form.append(key, api_data[key]);
            }
        }

        // Post the form data to the API
        const response = await axios.post('https://mylaravelbackend.com/api/register_independent_user', form, {
            headers: form.getHeaders(),

        });

        console.log(response);
        // console.log('Data posted successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

I am passing this type of object in api_data
{
   full_name: escrt.full_name,
   email: `${escrt.full_name}${random_number}@email.com`,
   phone_number: escrt.phone_number,
   display_name: escrt.full_name,
   age: escrt.age,
   nationality: escrt.nationality,
   ethnicity: escrt.ethnicity,
   ...
}

My laravel controller function for this api
// register independent escrt
    public function register_independent_escrt(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
        ...
}


I have more codes in the api function cant show those. for now i am returning all requests but return is data: [] blank array means no value is going to the laravel backend

maybe you can show the payload on networks?
